# How to add table in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013. When I try to add table into database, it shows only two option **"refresh and properties"**.

There is no SQL Server Data  tool for Visual Studio 2013 if any send me link where I can download it.

Any other way to add table?

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the SSDT? You can download here 2005-2016:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

or here for older versions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx